# What is MATLAB equivalent of Java direct loop over elements?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

In Java I can directly loop over elements in an array, e.g.:

```
int[] array = [1,2,3,4];
for (int elem: array){
  System.out.println(elem);
}
```

Instead of looping via indices

```
int[] array = [1,2,3,4];
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
  System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

How can I do the same in MATLAB?

Comment: In my eyes the down vote is justified. Instead of asking "How can I do the same in MATLAB?" you could just have tried to actually DO it, the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/for.html) is very clear on everything you asked. This question does not show any effort and just because you got a very good answer (though it just extends the doc) - doesn't make the question better.

Comment: Agreed, documentation is clear. I did not come across it. And as far as I understand the SO down votes have to be used with caution and extreme cases -- as I understand as a SO user I should help improve the questions rather than throwing them out throw them by [down voting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down). I am pretty sure that expert SO users will agree with me. Question like "what did you try" in the comments can help improve questions and as well as teach new users to write better questions.

Comment: @Bob, downvotes on questions should _not_ be used with extreme caution. Have a look at this [meta question (and answer)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252747/2338750). Meta is mostly visited by what you would refer to as "expert SO users", so I would say it's safe to say that expert users won't necessarily agree with you. When that's said, leaving a comment when downvoting explaining the reason is a nice gesture. Also take a look at this meta post explaining how the community tries to [Optimize for pearls, not sand](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Matlab the two options analogous to those in your question are:

```
%// Loop via indices
array = [10 20 30 40];
for n = 1:numel(array)
   disp(array(n));
end

%// Loop over elements directly    
array = [10 20 30 40];
for elem = array
   disp(elem);
end
```

Some notes:

1. When looping via indices, the statement `for n = 1:1000` *does not create the whole array* `1:1000`. So you can safely write for example `for n = 1:inf` (and maybe then use a `break` within the loop).
2. When an array is proveded in the loop statement, Matlab loops *over columns*. So for example

   ```
   %// Loop over elements (columns) directly
   array = [10 20 30 40; 50 60 70 80];
   for elem = array
      disp(elem);
   end
   ```

   would set `elem` to `[10; 50]`, then `[20; 60]` etc
3. The array can be *any type*, not necessarily numeric (and the column rule still applies). For example,

   ```
   %// Loop over elements (columns) directly, using a cell array
   array = {'Hello', 'Hi'; 'Goodbye' 'Godspeed'};
   for elem = array
      disp(elem);
   end
   ```

   makes `elem` equal to the column cell array `{'Hello'; 'Goodbye'}` and then to `{'Hi'; 'Godspeed'}`